# Cannot find "Get Tools to Build Apps" to install Napa

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, beta, office-365-develop-tool

I have followed this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179924%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to login to Office 365 Preview and has got stuck at installation of Napa as I can't find the **Get Tools to Build Apps** link.

I will appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just came across a nice [blog](http://blog.brainlitter.com/2012/08/10/how-to-add-a-site-collection-for-enabling-napa-office-365-development-tools-in-sharepoint-office-365-preview/) which explained it all. 
What we need to start using Napa is create a developer site collection from Office 365 SharePoint Admin and get on with App building :)